# Escript files and .gitignore

Tags: elixir, gitignore, elixir-mix

I'm going through the `Programming Elixir` book and currently got to the point of creating a little console using `mix escript.build` (similar to this documentation example: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html#module-example)

Now, it produces an executable `myprojname` in the project folder, which is cool and good.

BUT I really don't want to track executables in source control.

Coming from .NET, I'm used to `.gitignore` just ignoring anything under the `/bin` path, but the binary Elixir generates is:

- in the project root
- has a different name in every project

What's the best practice for `.gitignore`-ing escript files in Elixir project?

So far I've added this line to `.gitignore` and it works:

```
myprojname
```

But is there a better way that I'm missing? (In .NET, pretty much all projects have the same .gitignore file, because anything to be ignored is usually under a pre-defined path such as `/bin`, `/obj` etc. or has an extension like `.solutionuseroptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it explicitly listed in your `.gitignore`. That's how [Livebook does, for example](https://github.com/livebook-dev/livebook/blob/main/.gitignore#L35).

One alternative way is using the `--path` option, where you can set a custom name or folder to compile the project. Make sure to ignore this path in `.gitignore`.

```
mix escript.build --path executable.ignoredextension
mix escript.build --path ./ignored_folder/executable
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I've been looking for